# Why does the terminal display in my vscode look different?

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal

So I initially used windows, but recently decided to switch to linux. In windows, my vscode terminal look like this:
[image]

It shows which directory I am in. But when i try vscode in linux, i get this on run:

[image]

It shows nothing but `sh-5.1`, which i don't know what is it. And  when i run a simple c program:
[image]

the output is on the same line as the `sh-5.1`. How to change the terminal to look like in windows? (not exactly the same, I mean at least show the directory and generate a newline when done running program)

Comment: `bash` and `sh` are different shells, read the terminal doc page of VSC on how to setup a new terminal configuration, configure the shell prompt to see other info

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply write:

```
bash
```

to your console since bash shell is the closest one to what you want. Your current shell is sh. To switch back to sh, you can write sh again. To see other available shells in your computer, you can write: `cat /etc/shells`

If you don't have bash installed on your computer (which is pretty unlikely), you can install it by:

```
sudo apt-get install bash
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fix it on the VSCode terminal or make it stay that way, go to Settings. Type 'Linux exec' in the search bar. You should see 'Terminal > External Linux Exec.' Change it to your preferred terminal, like mine, gnome-terminal
[you should see this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u76uB.png)
Change it to your preferred terminal.